# implemeting auto-complete using pure angularjs without any dependency

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

**UPDATE:** 
I have come to realized that below code is using jQuery-UI and in my requirement I'm suppose to work without any 3rd party dependencies.

so to rephrase my question, how can i change or convert the below code to use just native angularjs rather than using jQuery-ui?

I'm sorry if this is confused to @Roberto Linares & @risto

I have searched and found this directive and I think its light-weight its working as expected if you go to the below jsfiddle but as soon as I changed the version of angularjs to 1.2x (which currently using in my project) getting this error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at http://localhost:54893/scripts/directives/auto-complete.js:3:19
iElement.autocomplete({  <<<<ERROR
```

here is my code:

```
userApp.directive('autoComplete', function($timeout) {
     return function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
         iElement.autocomplete({
             source: scope[iAttrs.uiItems],
             select: function() {
                 $timeout(function() {
                     iElement.trigger('input');
                 }, 0);
             }
         });
     };
 });


<input auto-complete ui-items="names" ng-model="selected">
    selected = {{selected}}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sebmade/swfjT/light/
also I have noticed that in jsfiddle its using Jquery UI is that a dependency on this directive?
if you know any light-weight directive please let me know as well..

AngularJS directive with 1.2 version:
http://jsfiddle.net/abuhamzah/zx8twm2w/  (not working)

Thanks.

Comment: In your not working example you are missing the jQuery UI dependency.

Comment: yes I'm aware of that; so do I have to have `jQuery UI` dependency?

Comment: update my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/abuhamzah/zx8twm2w/1/  with jquery ui still does not work, note i am using 1.2 ver of angularjs

Comment: You do, because the `autocomplete` function you are calling is part of [jquery UI](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/), not part of Angular. That's why Angular says that the function is undefined if you don't include jQuery UI.

Comment: You should load jquery and jquery ui before loading angularjs. Check [this working fiddle with Angular 1.2](http://jsfiddle.net/j1bo2b66/)

Comment: I think that using JQuery UI with Angular is not the good way to go, how can i remove the jquery ui dependency? and make it work only anguarjs

Comment: AngularJS itself doesn't ship with autocomplete functionality or widgets. You have to combine it with a library that includes those. For example, jQuery UI, [Angular UI](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) or others.

Comment: @NickKahn i am trying implement your code in my ionic project but i am error like TypeError: iElement.autocomplete is not a function do you have any idea abut this error

Answer (score 4):

No need to create directive, just use below code.

Html:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control autocomplete" ng-model="selected" typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue">
```

Add this code in your controller :

```
$scope.selected = undefined;
$scope.states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois'];
```

Working Example : https://jsfiddle.net/0y3ntj4x/23/

Comment: can you please send a working demo for this question

Comment: @MohanGopi you can below code in angularJs controller: app.controller('appcontroller', function($scope){$scope.selected = undefined;
$scope.states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois'];})

Comment: Yes You need to call ui-bootstrap-tpls-X.XX.XX.js(ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.4.js i have used for above demo) which is mixed of bootstrap and angularJS

Comment: for angular 4 how to run it? will you provide better solution?

Comment: @PrasannaSasne please find the working example based on angular 4.XX As below : http://demo.vickram.me/angular-auto-complete/#!#simple-list . i suggest you to use [ npm install angular-auto-complete ] for download the repo files ... i hope it will be helpful for you

Answer (score 3):

you can use below concept to use this features:

```
<div class="container">
    <div ng-controller="mainCtrl" class="row-fluid">
        <form class="row-fluid">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                Country Name <input type="text" class="form-control autocomplete" ng-model="selected" typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>



 angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap'])
        .controller("mainCtrl", function ($scope) {
      //  $scope.selected = {id:'0',address:'Type 3 Letters'};
       $scope.selected = undefined;
    $scope.states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois'];
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0y3ntj4x/23/

Answer (score -2):

**Update**: This solution is with jquery ui, based on the poster's original question. See the other answer for an HTML5 solution

Later versions of angular complained that DefaultCtrl was undefined. I fixed it though:

```
var app = angular.module('MyModule', []);
app.directive('autoComplete', function($timeout) {
    return function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
            iElement.autocomplete({
                source: scope[iAttrs.uiItems],
                select: function() {
                    $timeout(function() {
                      iElement.trigger('input');
                    }, 0);
                }
            });
    };
}).controller('DefaultCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.names = ["john", "bill", "charlie", "robert", "alban", "oscar", "marie", "celine", "brad", "drew", "rebecca", "michel", "francis", "jean", "paul", "pierre", "nicolas", "alfred", "gerard", "louis", "albert", "edouard", "benoit", "guillaume", "nicolas", "joseph"];
});
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/risto1/jnswy9v3/).

Comment: I'm not sure what you have changed but I do have `DefaultCtrl` in this version but with `1.2 version` angulajs check this out  http://jsfiddle.net/abuhamzah/zx8twm2w/

Comment: In angular there's an 'angular world' and non-angular world. You need to register the controller with angular. The equivalent from my code would be something like: `.controller('DefaultCtrl', DefaultCtrl)`

Comment: I think that using JQuery UI with Angular is not the good way to go, how can i remove the jquery ui dependency?

Comment: I dont think this works without jquery-ui.. I hate such answers. Wannabee people trying to get reputation.